# Django Templatetags Import Error

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've been banging my head against this for a while, but can't seem to figure it out. 
I've got an app with a set of custom template tags:

```
from django import template
from crowd.models import Payment, Project, ProjectCategory

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def is_customer(user, project):
   try:
      return Payment.objects.filter(user=user, project=project).count() > 0
   except:
      return False
```

That throws:

```
'project_tags' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading crowd.templatetags.project_tags: No module named models
```

The app tree looks like:

```
crowd/
   -- __init__.py
   -- models.py
   templatetags/
      -- __init__.py
      -- project_tags.py
```

Importing from just models and crowd.models both give me the same error.

Traceback: [here](http://pastebin.com/6JYPT5qF)

### Update

I was working on something unrelated when I noticed this was broken, so I reverted to an earlier, known working version of the project. Still the same problem, so I think Daniels answer about the PYTHONPATH is correct, however, how can I repair this?

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['/Users/****/Documents/dev/product/src/Product', ...]
```

The __init__.py's are all there all the way down, and crowd is in Product, so shouldn't it be on the path?

### Update 2

I've done some investigating in the shell:

```
>>> from crowd.models import *
>>> from crowd.managers import *
>>> from crowd.constants import *
>>> from crowd.templatetags import *
>>> from crowd.templatetags import project_tags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Murph/Documents/dev/product/src/Product/crowd/templatetags/project_tags.py", line 4, in <module>
    from crowd.forms import SearchForm
  File "/Users/Murph/Documents/dev/product/src/Product/crowd/forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    from crowd.models import Payment, Project, ProjectUpdate, GalleryPhoto
ImportError: No module named models
>>>
```

Still don't know *why* specifically that's failing, especially since the blanket import works.

### Update 3

Took me a while to see that the shell command was giving a more useful message than the django one, which led to this:

Turns out it wasn't even related to project_tags directly, it just wasn't a very useful error message. The import in project_tags.py of:

```
 from crowd.forms import SearchForm
```

was calling:

```
from crowd.models import Payment, Project, RewardLevel, ProjectUpdate, GalleryPhoto
```

in forms.py, which should have been:

```
from models import Payment, Project, RewardLevel, ProjectUpdate, GalleryPhoto
```

I'll add this as the answer when I can, apparently can't until 8 hours later.

Comment: Template tags will sometimes throw this error when there's a problem with the tag or filter itself. I see you're registering a filter that accepts two parameters... I'm not sure how you'd implement that on the template side. To the best of my knowledge filters only accept one value.

Comment: @Brandon: [Custom filters can take one or two arguments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters). In this case, the filter would be used with `user|is_customer:project`

Comment: @georgebrock You're right, I was thinking he was trying to pass two variables in. I need more coffee :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to see that the shell command was giving a more useful message than the django one, which led to this:

Turns out it wasn't even related to project_tags directly, it just wasn't a very useful error message. The import in project_tags.py of:

```
 from crowd.forms import SearchForm
```

was calling:

```
from crowdfunder.models import Payment, Project, RewardLevel, ProjectUpdate, GalleryPhoto
```

in forms.py, which should have been:

```
from models import Payment, Project, RewardLevel, ProjectUpdate, GalleryPhoto
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `crowd` app itself is probably not on your Pythonpath. Either add it, or import from the project: `from myproject.crowd.models import Foo, Bar`.

Comment: How could I add it? It's in installed apps and stuff, but after navigating to some other pages on the site I think you're right. I've been working on this project for months, is there something that would all of a sudden break it out of my PYTHONPATH?

Comment: No need for "all of a sudden": if you've never tried to import it directly, it's probably never been there. As I say, in this case import via the project.

Comment: I'd like to keep this app pluggable, since it may be useful in the future open sourced after this project launches. Is there a way to repair/add it back to the PYTHONPATH so that I could continue dev without locking the source to this project for now? Also, see the update, not sure if it helps or not.

Comment: Just to add - he's running code from app.templatetags here, so .models doesn't exist, only 'app' has models - so crowd.models might suffice - but go with what Daniel says - he probably knows best.